# Extracting table data using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage - https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/ from which I want to extract name, url, sku and specifications (from table) of each product. I wrote the code below but I am getting an empty excel file. I have been trying to fix it for long but cant think of what is going wrong.

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=1
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/?p=" +str(page)
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("h2", {"class":"product-name"}):
            href=link.find("a")['href']
            title = link.string
            worksheet.write(row_i, 0, title)
            each_item(href)
            print(href)
            #print(title)
        page+=1

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(item_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"specifications "})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.find_all('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('all_appended.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Title")
    
cpap_spider(1)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: This is a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927603/not-able-to-extract-table-data-from-a-webpage.

Comment: have deleted it. there was some error in the last one. thanks!

Comment: it is for extracting from pdf..

Comment: Wrong question sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in your class name `{"class":"specifications "})`, removed and the excel file was generated with multiple specs columns and data lines.

As a suggestion, if you're willing to add some extra libraries, you can use `pandas` do read the specifications table as data frames with [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) and use the included function [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to write an excel file (which can use the same engine `xlsxwriter` you're already using) without worrying about incrementing rows and columns.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

AGENT = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
BASE_URL = "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/"
CATG_URL = "category/369/transport-wheelchairs/?p="


def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    chair_names = ["Specs"]
    chair_tables = ''
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = BASE_URL+CATG_URL+str(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
            url, headers=AGENT).content, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("h2", {"class": "product-name"}):
            href = link.find("a")['href']
            title = link.string
            chair_name = href.replace(BASE_URL+"product/","")
            chair_names.append(chair_name[:20])
            chair_tables += each_item(href)
            print(href)
        page += 1
    return [chair_names, chair_tables]


def each_item(item_url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
        item_url, headers=AGENT).content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "specifications"})
    if table:
        return str(table)


chair_name, chair_list = cpap_spider(1)

# create a list of dataframes from html tables
df = pd.read_html(chair_list)
# merge the spec. tables list into one dataframe
all_chairs = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=[0], how='outer'), df)

# add chair names as indices
all_chairs.columns = chair_name
all_chairs.set_index("Specs", drop=True, inplace=True)

# transpose to get chairs as index and specs as columns
all_chairs = all_chairs.T

all_chairs.to_excel("all_appended.xlsx")
```

Output from **all_appended.xlsx**

[image: wheelchair_site_data]